# Auto-Resizing UITextView in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview, uistoryboard

I'm setting up a scroll view that displays some content. I'm trying to figure out how to change the scroll view size according to the amount of text within the text view (and of course change the text view height, but keep the width the same). I am using a Storyboard for the scroll view. Inside the view controller is the scroll view, which contains a container view (this is where the text view is kept). The text view I am talking about is under where it says content description. I have tried a bunch of different approaches but haven't found one that works. Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thanks! (it's also worth noting that I am presenting this view controller using the DeckTransition library)

My Xcode storyboard https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEMSF.jpg
How it looks so far in the simulator https://i.stack.imgur.com/irfEO.jpg

Comment: 0

Refer to the link below:--

Setting Dynamic Height to UIScrollView Swift

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH24-SW1

Comment: @MayankWadhwa that link does not help me. I tried doing what they said. Could you please explain further?

Comment: If you disable scrolling on your text view, it will auto-size itself just like a label with number of lines set to zero.

Comment: @DonMag when I disable the scrolling it does not resize itself. It just stays the same height as before but now the text is cut off

Comment: Do you have a height constraint set on it? If so, delete that.

Comment: update the content size of a UIScrollView based on its contained subviews:var contentRect = CGRect.zero

for view in mainScrollView.subviews {
   contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
}
mainScrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out that I had some constraints that were not allowing the text view to resize properly. I disabled the scrolling on the text view, removed a height constraint that was on the scroll view and the content view, and now everything seems to be working. I appreciate all the advice given! You guys are super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you set `scrollEnabled` to false, text view will fit its content. If it does not work, you should check your constraints. e.g. content hugging priority, compression resistance priority. To make sure the text view to shrink smaller than the intrinsic content size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example to try. Tapping the "Change Text" button will switch between short, medium and long amounts of text in the text view, giving this result:

[image][image][image]

Here is all the code needed (all it does is change the text - nothing else):

```
import UIKit

class TextViewinScrollViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var theTextView: UITextView!

    var i = 0

    var strings = [
        "This is a Short amount of text.",
        "This is a Medium amount of text. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.",
        "This is a Long amount of text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.",
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        theTextView.text = strings[i]
    }

    @IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any) {
        i += 1
        if i >= strings.count {
            i = 0
        }
        theTextView.text = strings[i]
    }

}
```

And here's the Storyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14460.31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="HAr-gQ-Ow4">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14460.20"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Text Viewin Scroll View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="0zs-mA-Zcw">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="HAr-gQ-Ow4" customClass="TextViewinScrollViewController" customModule="XC10SWScratch" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="oNR-og-qiK">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="XBn-Je-V51">
                                <rect key="frame" x="40" y="60" width="295" height="567"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="oNQ-i1-b49" userLabel="Container">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="295" height="675.5"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="VAf-T0-cKT">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="295" height="240"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="240" id="NzL-9L-Ybs"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="K3u-yi-BbX">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="51.5" y="252" width="192" height="26"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92143100499999997" green="0.92145264149999995" blue="0.92144101860000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <inset key="contentEdgeInsets" minX="10" minY="4" maxX="10" maxY="4"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="Change Text in Text View"/>
                                                <connections>
                                                    <action selector="didTap:" destination="HAr-gQ-Ow4" eventType="touchUpInside" id="dnw-ff-qw3"/>
                                                </connections>
                                            </button>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Content Description" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="gXD-0q-Avm">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="290" width="153.5" height="20.5"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92143100499999997" green="0.92145264149999995" blue="0.92144101860000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" scrollEnabled="NO" editable="NO" text="This is the Text View" textAlignment="natural" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Mwg-70-9L2">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="322.5" width="255" height="33"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                                            </textView>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="1ox-xZ-Teo" userLabel="Example View">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="367.5" width="255" height="300"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92143100499999997" green="0.92145264149999995" blue="0.92144101860000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="300" id="hXk-ck-CvF"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                                <string key="text">Example View
(300-pts Height)</string>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.83234566450000003" blue="0.47320586440000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstItem="gXD-0q-Avm" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="K3u-yi-BbX" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="12" id="7gX-pC-zmh"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="Mwg-70-9L2" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="oNQ-i1-b49" secondAttribute="width" constant="-40" id="9pZ-ja-g7R"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="Mwg-70-9L2" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="oNQ-i1-b49" secondAttribute="centerX" id="Byo-5N-WXf"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="VAf-T0-cKT" secondAttribute="trailing" id="FyF-by-edM"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="1ox-xZ-Teo" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="Mwg-70-9L2" secondAttribute="width" id="Lic-3Q-vWZ"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="1ox-xZ-Teo" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="MQK-MS-dCA"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="K3u-yi-BbX" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="oNQ-i1-b49" secondAttribute="centerX" id="UPN-FD-gxb"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="K3u-yi-BbX" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="VAf-T0-cKT" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="12" id="WMi-Vl-xBu"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="1ox-xZ-Teo" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="oNQ-i1-b49" secondAttribute="centerX" id="dno-nR-zvQ"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="Mwg-70-9L2" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="gXD-0q-Avm" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="12" id="fDe-GP-gs4"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="VAf-T0-cKT" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="oNQ-i1-b49" secondAttribute="top" id="hRj-XY-fnb"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="gXD-0q-Avm" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="oNQ-i1-b49" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="ks5-IH-yrt"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="1ox-xZ-Teo" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Mwg-70-9L2" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="12" id="lYY-L9-pb6"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="VAf-T0-cKT" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="oNQ-i1-b49" secondAttribute="leading" id="urO-i9-GQ7"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </view>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.46202266219999999" green="0.83828371759999998" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="oNQ-i1-b49" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="XBn-Je-V51" secondAttribute="top" id="FGL-wN-OHg"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="oNQ-i1-b49" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="XBn-Je-V51" secondAttribute="leading" id="f4T-Mh-ZdB"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="oNQ-i1-b49" secondAttribute="bottom" id="qwX-hf-UtO"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="oNQ-i1-b49" secondAttribute="trailing" id="tdW-x1-DtX"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="oNQ-i1-b49" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="XBn-Je-V51" secondAttribute="width" id="urs-jZ-3Hi"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="VsF-QR-ZgP" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="XBn-Je-V51" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="40" id="bww-Xy-uZ6"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="XBn-Je-V51" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="VsF-QR-ZgP" secondAttribute="top" constant="40" id="dP4-Ax-cgr"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="XBn-Je-V51" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="VsF-QR-ZgP" secondAttribute="leading" constant="40" id="eof-fi-9Ml"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="VsF-QR-ZgP" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="XBn-Je-V51" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="40" id="euP-M7-rBT"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="VsF-QR-ZgP"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="theTextView" destination="Mwg-70-9L2" id="IWV-hn-TRM"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="q25-D5-Cge" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-114.40000000000001" y="58.920539730134934"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```